# Смещение элемента массива

Tags: objective-c, swift

Есть задача с [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation) вкратце нужно совершить сдвиг вправо на K, определенное количество раз N (лучше прочитать условие на hr потому что я очень тупо объяснил :С )

у меня получилось что то такое но это понятное дело неправильно

```
var massiv = [1,2,3]

func shift(var arr: [Int], much: Int) -> [Int] {

    for _ in 0..<much {
            var z = arr.removeFirst()
            arr.append(z)
    }
    return arr
}

shift(massiv, much: 2)
```

**Текст задачи:**

> Джон Ватсон хочет проверить Шерлока Холмса. Он дал ему массив A0,A1
>   ... AN-1 . Выполнил некоторое преобразование массива, а затем задал
>   Шерлоку Q вопросов. Шерлок чувствует, что преобразование, которое
>   применил Джон, называется циклический сдвиг вправо на K. Циклический
>   сдвиг вправо на 1 преобразует массив A0,A1 ... AN-1 в AN-1,A0 ...
>   AN-2. Джон применил сдвиг на единицу K раз.
>
> Помогите Шерлоку ответить на вопросы. Каждый вопрос описывается целым
>   числом X, в ответ на вопрос Шерлок должен выписать элемент AX
>   преобразованного массива.
>
> Формат входных данных  Первая строка содержит три целых числа,
>   записанных через пробел, N, K и Q.  Следующая строка содержит N целых
>   чисел, записанных через пробел, - массив A.  Каждая из следующих Q
>   строк содержит целое число X - описание текущего вопроса.
>
> Формат выходных данных  Для каждого вопроса выведите соответствующий
>   элемент преобразованного массива.
>
> Ограничения 
>  1 <= N <= 105 
>  1 <= A[i] <= 105 
>  1 <= K <=
>   105 
>  1 <= Q <= 500 
>  0 <= X <= N-1
>
> Пример входных данных #00
>
> 3 2 3
>  1 2 3
>  0
>  1
>  2
>
> Пример выходных данных #00
>  2
>  3
>  1
>  Пояснения к примерам
>   
>  После первого циклического сдвига на 1 массив станет равен: 3 1
>   2. 
>  После второго он станет равен: 2 3 1. 
>  0-й элемент массива равен 2. 
>  1-й элемент массива равен 3. 
>  2-й элемент массива
>   равен 1.

Comment: а можно условие скопировать в вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вполне рабочее у Вас решение. Могу предложить еще парочку:

1 Классическое решение

```
func moveRight(arr: [Int], step: Int) -> [Int] {
    if step % arr.count == 0 {
        return arr
    }
    var array = arr
    var first: Int
    for _ in 0..<step % arr.count {
        first = array[0]
        for i in 0..<array.count-1 {
            array[i] = array[i+1]
        }
        array[array.count-1] = first
    }
    return array
}
```

2. Мне нравится больше всего:

```
func moveRight(arr: [Int], step: Int) -> [Int] {
    if step % arr.count == 0 {
        return arr
    }
    return Array(arr.suffixFrom(step % arr.count) + arr.prefix(step % arr.count))
}
```

3 Ваш оптимизированный вариант:

```
func moveRight(arr: [Int], step: Int) -> [Int] {
    if step % arr.count == 0 {
        return arr
    }
    var array = arr
    for _ in 0..<step % arr.count {
        let a = array.removeFirst()
        array.append(a)
    }
    return array
}
```

Ну и насчет правильно-неправильно можно развести дискуссию практически по любому вопросу.

Среднее время выполнения:

```
Количество элементов в массиве 10
Смещение 0..<10000
1 вариант            2 вариант            3 вариант
5.91185092926025e-06 1.23924016952515e-05 2.00728416442871e-05

Количество элементов в массиве 100
Смещение 0..<10000
1 вариант            2 вариант            3 вариант
0.000460050988197327 4.05452013015747e-05 0.000183036613464355 

Количество элементов в массиве 1000
Смещение 0..<1000
1 вариант            2 вариант            3 вариант
0.00442803382873535  4.55737113952637e-05 0.000202417373657227
```

Comment: обычно еще ставиться в начале проверка `if(step == arr.count) return arr;`

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, точно, спасибо, подправил.

Answer (score 2):

Нет смысла перемещать объекты или что-то делать с массивом, надо просто вычислить нужный индекс. Вот мое решение задачи:

```
let nkq = readLine()!.characters.split(" ").map{Int(String($0))!}
let n = nkq[0]
let k = n - nkq[1] % n
let q = nkq[2]

var arr = readLine()!.characters.split(" ").map{Int(String($0))!}

for _ in 1...q {
    let i = (k + Int(readLine()!)!) % n
    print(arr[i])
}
```